# Servlet returning empty response to ajax after calling another servlet within a servlet

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I have written a servlet

```
try {
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/someservlet");
    rd.include(request, response);
    test(request, response);
} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

test() method returns a json response like this

```
response.getWriter().write(outputJSON);
```

but the ajax is not recieving any json response I have check the network tab in chrome response is empty.
If I remove the request dispatcher part then everything works perfect.
I need to get the json data along with calling the above mentioned servlet
Kindly assist me .

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the log? What does `/someservlet` do, i.e. does it have any output?

Comment: No exceptions in the logs it even prints the outputJSON in server logs but empty in browser also /someservlet is basically to logout the existing user

Comment: Your code is fine, the only way this implementation not return the result is if `test()` is not called by an exception, e.g. Could you please update your question with more code (like the other servlet call, and if your first servlet class does smth else..) ?